# Why is my modal-header and modal-footer causing my websites layout to mess up

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a basic site with a grid layout and and a modal with a login form. However, I noticed after adding tags for the modal header and footer the layout completely screws up and leaves a large gap in the middle. The page currently looks like [image: Top of page] [image: Page bottom]

The expected outcome for the page should be like here:
https://codepen.io/mor10/pen/QvmLpd
and if I do not include the modal footer and header tags it works as expected. The current code for and surrounding the modal is this:

[image: As an image for formatting]

Code for sake of being able to post with codepen link:

```
  <main id="content" class="main-content">
        <!-- Modal for logging in -->
            
        <h2>Main content area</h2>
        <p>The main content area is where the magic happens. Right now, the main content is on the left and the sidebar is on the right. If you go into the markup for this document and add <code>dir="rtl"</code> to the <code>html</code> element, the two elements will swap spaces because CSS Grid honors text direction.</p>
        <div id="loginModal" class="modal">
        
                    <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Login</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="">
                    <label for="fname">Username:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="user"><br>
                    <label for="lname">Password:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="password"><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an account?</p><p>Create one</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
      </div>

    </main>
```

It's very strange to me that the modal is affecting the layout, but only when the header and footer of the modal are used. On previous sites I have made, I have used multiple modals and not had this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a closing `</div>` tag without an opening one:

```
<main id="content" class="main-content">
    <!-- Modal for logging in -->
        
    <h2>Main content area</h2>
    <p>The main content area is where the magic happens. Right now, the main content is on the left and the sidebar is on the right. If you go into the markup for this document and add <code>dir="rtl"</code> to the <code>html</code> element, the two elements will swap spaces because CSS Grid honors text direction.</p>
    
    <div id="loginModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Login</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="">
                    <label for="fname">Username:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="user"><br>
                    <label for="lname">Password:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="password"><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an account?</p><p>Create one</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- this should be removed -->
</main>
```

Comment: its always something ridiculously simple with html, can't believe I didn't catch that, thanks!

Comment: @SourOddity you're welcome! I recommend you to adjust your code format a little bit. These errors are easier to see when code is properly formatted :)

Comment: Thank you, it definitely is a bit messy, what would you recommend I do to help with the formatting a bit?

Comment: @SourOddity you can check this: https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Formatting_Rules